# git: best way to resolve merge conflicts in notes branch of git

Tags: git

what is the best approach to resolving merge conflicts in notes branch of a git repository?

I ran into a scenario where in when I try to fetch the content of the notes branch from the remote repository, I get an error saying non-fast-forward, fetch rejected. Suggestions?

Comment: I found out a way to do a merge in notes branch of git. Below is the approach I am using. Please let me know if I am right/wrong.

1.  git checkout refs/notes/commits
2.  git fetch origin refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/origin/commits
3.  git merge FETCH_HEAD
4.  git update-ref refs/notes/commits

Please let me know if this is ok???

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to do a merge in notes branch of git. Below is the approach I am using. Please let me know if I am right/wrong.

```
git checkout refs/notes/commits
git fetch origin refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/origin/commits 
git merge FETCH_HEAD 
git update-ref refs/notes/commits
```

Please let me know if this is the right approach???